# Google Fit Credentials: works on Production, not on Development

Tags: android, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-fit

## Goal

I am developing an App that works with Google Fit, but for some reason I can't get them both versions to work at the same time.

Before recreating the credentials again, it was the other way around: *Development* was working and *Production* wasn't.

## Credentials & Google Api

I enabled the Api and added the credentials:

[Google Api website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0iip.png)

## KeyStore

The generated KetStore contains 2 keys, one for production and another one for development. Each one was set in the *Credentials* page accordingly to its package name (see *Android App*).

[Terminal dump of KeyStore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mdGY.png)

## Android App

Our App has 2 different package names:

- *xxx.yyy.app* for Production
- *xxx.yyy.development* for Development

This was achieved with the Gradle config, using flavours. This way we have 2 Apps on the mobile for testing purposes.

## Question

I have no idea what conflict it's happening that doesn't let me have them both working.

I only have 1 working at the same time, and the one that doesn't work gets `CANCELLED` result on the LogCat.

Maybe having the same package prefix (*xxx.yyy.*) is an issue and therefore, reads the wrong credential?

Any suggestions is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I guess there is no issue in using the same package prefix since the package names should be based on a domain name that you control or have permission to use. Refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038390/can-someone-else-use-the-same-package-name-prefix). The error `CANCELLED` which you are encountering means that you are using the wrong debug.keystore. Here's a related [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238839/can-two-different-apps-have-the-same-packagename) which might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `Android Studio` wasn't using my `keystore` when compiling the `APK`. It was still using the default `debug.keystore` with alias `AndroidDebugKey` and `android` password.

For some reason, it wasn't reading my signing config for the `development` environment, but it was for `production`.

In order to check what signing is each `Build Variant` using:

- Open a project
- Open `Gradle` tab on the right
- Expand <*your_project*> ==> Tasks ==> Android
- Double click on `singingReport` (this will create a `Gradle` type `Run/Debug Configuration`)
- Open `Gradle Console` located in the bottom right

At this point you should see some of these:

```
Variant: developmentDebug
Config: debug
Store: /Users/<username>/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
SHA1: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Valid until: <date>
```

Make sure the `SHA1` for each variant is the same as the one specified in the `Credentials` page.